# Template code for non-polymorphic types using lambda in C++14 or C++17

Tags: templates, lambda, polymorphism, c++14

I have callbacks using a lambda which I am trying to turn into a template. The problem is that the event base-class is non-polymorphic to derived-classes. Please see the code below.
**What I want to do is somehow have template code for callback so that I don't have to write multiple copies of the same code**.

```
  auto my_lambda = [](std::shared_ptr<EventBase> event)
  {
    if (std::is_same<T, TypeA>::value) {
      if (event->EventType() != TypeA::EventID()) {
        return;
      }
    } else if(std::is_same<T, TypeB>::value) {
      if (event->EventType() != TypeB::EventID()) {
        return;
      }
    }

    auto event_type =
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventA>(event); //This causes problem when trying to
 make it into a template -- see commented code below -- what I tried -- this fails

   // if (std::is_same<T, TypeB>::value)
   // {
   //   event_type =
   //       std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventB>(event);
   // }

    auto &buffer = event_type->Buffer();
    rval = other_service->Set(T::Buffer, buffer);
    if (rval != OK)
    {
      return;
    }
  };

//Calling lambda here to subscribe to event
  store_id = some_service->Subscribe(T::EventId, my_lambda);
```

Please help!

Comment: "event base-class is non-polymorphic to derived-classes". That's a gross misuse of inheritance. `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventA>(event)` This only works for polymorphic classes, templates or not.

Comment: If `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventA>(event)` even compiles, then `EventBase` is in fact polymorphic. The question is unclear. What's `T`, `TypeA` and `TypeB`? It would be best if you show a [mcve] of your working non-template code, and a non-working example of a template code you are trying to turn it into.

Comment: Why I am saying its not polymorphic is because when I try to do something like below.. this fails.

`std::shared_ptr<EventBase> event_type;


`if (std::is_same<T, TypeA>::value) {`
 ` event_type =
          `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventA>(event); 
`} 
`else if (std::is_same<T, TypeB>::value) {
   `event_type =
          `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<EventB>(event);
    }

   ` auto &buffer = event_type->Buffer(); // Event base does not have Buffer() member func.

-----------------------------

Comment: T, TypeA, TypeB -- This whole code is within template func.. and I am just trying to compare template type T to TypeA and TypeB typenames. Please let me know if this information is required too. I dint think its required to address what I am trying to resolve.

Comment: So, for eg -- if template type is TypeA - I want to have Event casted to EventA and if its TypeB then I want event to be casted to EventB -- that is my end goal here.

Comment: The example doesn't imply that the base class is not polymorphic. It implies that you are not using C++ types correctly. They don't work the way you seem to think they work.

Comment: What would be right way of doing this.. if I want template typeA to invoke casting for EventA and typeB to invoke EventB ?